# Genral Muktzeh question

Tags: shabbat, muktzeh, halacha

What are the overall rules of Muktzeh and its categories?

When is one allowed to move a Muktza object and for what purpose?

Comment: There is a Sefer called the Halachos of Muktza by Rabbi Yisroel P Bodner that clarifies these issues very well.

Comment: As there is artscrool from Rabbi Cohen.Here is a challenge to put in a few words or parraphs the general terms something way more bite size that is shavah lkol Nefesh

Comment: Sounds a lot like a question someone could write a whole book about....

Answer (score 3):

An oversimplification, since that's what's being sought: *Muktze* is something (a) unusable, (b) valuable-cum-fragile, or (c) useless for non-*m'lacha* uses, or (d) a support for one of the above. Something useless or valuable-cum-fragile can't be moved or used. Something useless for non-*m'lacha* uses can be moved only if it's needed for a permitted use or occupying needed space. A support for *muktze* has the status of type of *muktze* on it. See one of the books mentioned in the comments on the question, or [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR), for details; certainly don't rely practically on anything in this answer.

---

*Update:* [A better answer, which serves also as an answer to this question, was posted later to another question.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13745)

Comment: (I've reverted another's edits to my answer, yielding my original version, which started with a disclaimer that I think is important to include.)

Comment: Just in response Rashi and many other commentaries where famous for being able to take very broad topics and put it in a few words that is a reflection of an amazing grasp of a topic not an oversimplification.As any teacher or Rav must do also mike very all encompassing topics bite size and that is what I am looking for somone with a full grasp of the topic to summarize in a few words or pargraphs

Comment: Simchas Torah, even the Mechaber wrote over 80 simanim on muktze.  msh wrote a practical summary which covers most contemporary issues in a general sense, but there is much more (eg- things that were not muktze but are now, things that could go either way depending on you intent/action before shabbos, what if you already picked up the muktze, potential damage to people, abnormal movement leniencies, etc.

Comment: I seem to recall when learning Mes. Shabbos (perhaps a Tos.)  that the idea of Muktze mechamas chisaron kis is that since it was fragile/expensive, you would not use it except for its forbidden use, there fore you are mekatze it.  In other words, not that because it's expensive you don't want to move it, but that it moves from the category of kli shemelachto l'issur where a person still retains the right of usage to muktze mechamas gufo where there is no permitted use.  This doesn't seem to be the explanation of contemporary sefarim.  Has anyone come accross this idea?

Comment: @R'SimchasTorah, I agree with your comment. But I'm not Rashi, and I'm not someone with a full grasp of the topic. So my caveat that that's an oversimplification is I think in order.

Comment: A good link and or a longer overview would have been fine.

Comment: Is this question in a category of "asking a question which requires a book to answer"?